# status bar notification icon color

Tags: android

I'm working with android application to publish Google play store. as I know the lollipop and above versions of android support only white colord icons. when I use a multicolour icon with the inbuilt emulator of android studio, it shows white . but when I use that apk in a Samsung, huawei, asus or htc device it shows multicolour status bar icon correctly. my problem is why it is happening and how can I filter multicolour icon working devices and not working devices?

link to some example screenshots added in the first comment.

[link to the screenshot of oreo device with multicolor icon not showing correctly](https://ibb.co/g4UYBm)

[link to the screenshot of another oreo device with multicolor icon showing correctly](https://ibb.co/jPf1xR)

Comment: Please insert the screenshots into the question and not in a comment.

Comment: cannot add in the question, because it needs 10 reputation to add pictures directly to the question.

Comment: this is android oreo device preview with white icon.   https://ibb.co/g4UYBm

Comment: this is another android oreo device with correctly showing icon. https://ibb.co/jPf1xR